# After I run JS file this happen so many times

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[vscode terminal after pressing run button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbpcY.png)
this happen `

> PS E:\path\path\path> node "e:\path\path\path\index.js"
> (node:22700) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> e:\path\path\path\index.js:1
> import { player } from 'player.js'; true
> ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.16.0

`
in myproject there is not many complicated thing in there just to try react with JS and HTML

I'm quite new to programming so I don't know much please help me fix this

this is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, everyone!</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

another example is :

```
export class player{
    constructor(name, country){
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
    }
    whoIsHe(){
        console.log(`${this.name} was born in ${thiscountry}`)
    }

}
```

and

```
import { player } from 'player.js'; true

const someone= new player("someone", "Thailand");

someone.whoIsHe();
```

Comment: That button is tied to a Node.js runtime, by default vanilla Node.js cannot transpile and or execute *JSX*. You need to use a transformer to transform your *JSX* syntax to React. Popular options are Babel and TypeScript. Furthermore, usually in your scenario with a standalone React island, the JavaScript is generally executed on the *client* side, not *server* side. See also webpack, vite and Next.js for examples of managed ways of using React.

Comment: try to use require() method instead of import {} from, and use module.exports instread of export